# How can I change the open file action of solution explorer items?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

It is irritating (and counter-intuitive) that with the files for a Windows Forms application, *.cs is opened in the designer while *.Designer.cs is opened in the code view. I want to be able to change that as I have the following file structure

```
Root
|----Forms
     |----MainWindow.cs
          |----MainWindow.Designer.cs
          |----MainWindow.Events.cs
          |----MainWindow.resx
     |----
|----
|
|----Program.cs
```

That is a simplified version but it shows what I am trying to explain. I want to be able to double-click on MainWindow.cs and MainWindow.Events.cs to open them in Code View but when I double-click on MainWindow.Designer.cs, I want it to open up in Designer View.

I can't find a solution so if there truly is no solution to this, I don't mind a botch/hack.

Comment: I don't know of any settings that control this in WinForms, there are some settings similar to what you are looking for in WPF, but unfortunately that won't help you.  The only work around that I know of it to manually right-click the file, and choose to view code, or the designer, but I doubt that will be very satisfying.  It may be possible to write an extension to do this, but doing so won't be easy or fast.

Comment: There are keybaord shortcuts of `F7` to show code, and `Shift` + `F7` to show the designer.